# Angular 2 app not loading in Chrome - Stuck at loading... - Backend written in Java Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, angular, angular2-services, angular2-forms

I am new to angular2 and need help. I am working on an angular2 app whose backend is written in Java Spring. The app worked perfectly before. I did not change any code but now when I load it in chrome , it is stuck at loading... I inspected the console but there is no error. If i try to open it in firefox or safari it loads perfectly but in firefox i am unable to submit a form (maybe compatibility issues?).

The app was written in "angular2": "2.0beta.0-.14" . As Angular2 RC5 has been released so is the code outdated? 
Should i have to make changes in the code?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>BMIS</title>
    <base href="/">

    <!-- Angular JS  -->

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>


    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->

    <script>
        System.config({

            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js',
                }
            },
            map: {
                "angular2-jwt": "node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js"
            }
        });
        System.import('app/main')
                .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

    <!-- Angular JS  -->


    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->

    <!-- Timeline css -->
    <link href="assets/css/timeline.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Timeline css -->


    <!-- Navigation -->
    <link href="assets/css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="assets/js/navbar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Navigation -->

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->


</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "abcd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "typings": "typings",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0beta.0-.14",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ng2-radio-group": "0.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.24",
    "zone.js": "0.6.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.1.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.9",
    "typings": "^0.7.9"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to follow the upgrade path. First step will be to check the upgrade path to RC1:

http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/post/2016/05/10/upgrading-from-angular-2-beta-17-to-angular-2-rc1/

Upgrading shouldn't be a problem if you don't have `routing`

Next thing will be upgrade to **RC5**. The main breaking changes is bootstrapping using `NgModules`. Check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html for exact steps.

Comment: I will try this. I also have routing in my project so what should i do? The tutorial says to use router-deprecated because the new one is nasty.